# Как создать QString в куче

Tags: c++

Если я объявлю переменную в заголовочном файле

```
private:
  QString test;
```

Она возьмёт себе память из кучи?

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду? В смысле где будет аллоцировано `test`? Если так, то там же где вы создаёте переменную класса

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, то есть это значит если я объявлю переменную test в классе Example, а потом сделаю Example *ex = new Example() то и test будет в куче? дело в том, что в QString должна быть большая строка на 2 МБ и я не хотел бы её выделять в стеке

Comment: QString не является примитивом и сильно сомневаюсь что в стеке будет храниться что-то больше чем указатель. особенно учитывая динамический размер QString до 2^30 символов

Comment: Вы путаете выделение памяти под переменную QString и под строку в ней хранящуюся. Размер переменной QString всегда одинаков, независимо от того какого размера строку он содержит, так как внутри у него просто указатель на участок памяти в куче